# Switching TextView backgorund on button click

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

Is there any way to switch `TextView` background when I press a button?

The background are in the drawable folder, I need something like this:

```
public void ChangeBG(){
    Button mybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //SET  R.DRAWABLE.BG2  AS BACKGROUND

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think its simple

```
 textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image);
```

Comment: @ToastMan if my answer satisfied your question then kindly mark it as tik, Thanks.